# Android: Moving Button to different LinearLayout messes up Click Events

Tags: android-layout, button, view, onclick, android-linearlayout

I've done professional development for over 14 years, but I am learning Android development.  I came across a scenario that boggles my mind.  I designed a simple layout, then decided to move some of the buttons from one LinearLayout to another LinearLayout within the same layout file.

Now, since moving the buttons, the click events are wired to the wrong buttons!  It's as if the resource ids of the buttons were order-dependent.

BEFORE (works correctly):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/previous_button" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/true_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/true_button"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/false_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/false_button" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

AFTER (works incorrectly):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/true_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/true_button"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/false_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/false_button" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/previous_button" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see in the "AFTER" code, I want the previous/next buttons to be below the True/False buttons.  And, if you look the designer, it's flawless -- perfect!  But, the controller hiccups:

- True button now becomes the Previous button
- False button now becomes the True button
- Previous button now becomes the False button
- Next button works as it should.

Here is the code that is wiring up the click events (sorry if the code looks lame, I am going through an Android tutorial book, so please don't critique it, it's not mine!):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    mQuestionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
    mQuestionTextView.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;

                    updateQuestion();
                }
            });

    mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override 
                public void onClick(View v) { 
                    checkAnswer(true);
                }   
            });
    mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    checkAnswer(false);
                }
            });

    mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;

                    updateQuestion();
                }
            });

    mPreviousButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previous_button);
    mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int length = mQuestionBank.length;
                    mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + (length-1)) % length;
                    updateQuestion();
                }
            });

    updateQuestion();

}
```

So these resource ids must be order specific; I can't explain it any other way.  The problem is that I don't know how to make my buttons do what they want in the layout that I want.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I managed to fix it.  In Eclipse/ADT I went to Project -> Clean... and that seemed to do the trick. And yes, it was an issue with the resource ids!  I tried posting a nice screen shot of the git repository before/after so you can see what lines from the R.java file changed but I don't have enough reputation points.  Sorry.